# How to show a caret in a WebView2 control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webview2

I would like to see a caret in my WebView2 implementation.

For doing this, I tried this:

```
var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
options.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--enable-caret-browsing";
var _createTask = CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(
    null,
    "C:\\",
    options);
_createTask.ContinueWith(
    (task) =>
    {
        RunOnUiThread(
            () =>
            {
                EnsureCoreWebView2Async(task.Result);
            });
    });
```

... but I still don't see a caret inside the WebView2 control. Why not, and how can I show it?

The `--enable-caret-browsing` feature is described [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#enable-caret-browsing).

Comment: Where is that code placed? I would guess that EnsureCoreWebView2Async is called from a different place before your code here calls it

Comment: @NineBerry: No, I'm sorry, I checked it again: `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync` will be called before the first `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` call.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I uploaded my code and edited my question for the link.

Comment: Please post the code here or use an established source code sharing site. The link leads to as site that tries to install malware on the computer.

Comment: @NineBerry: If you would know an answer, you would post it. Since you don't answer, it's senseless to support you.

Comment: This feature is a user choice. It's toggled pressing F7. A dialog informs of the current state, so it acts as remainder. IIRC, the user acknowledging the setting's state is more relevant. If you specify that option like that, you probably disable the feature entirely